# Magento 2 admin user role not custom menu

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml, admin-controller

Hi my custom menu not showing admin user role.

etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="Retailers_Company::retailers" title="Retailers" module="Retailers_Company" sortOrder="10" resource="Retailers_Company::retailers"/>
    <add id="Retailers_Company::add_new" title="Retailers Account Management" module="Retailers_Company" sortOrder="20" parent="Retailers_Company::retailers" action="company/vendor" resource="Retailers_Company::add_new"/>
    <add id="Retailers_Company::add" title="Add Account Manager" module="Retailers_Company" sortOrder="20" parent="Retailers_Company::retailers" action="company/index/add" resource="Retailers_Company::add"/>
    <add id="Retailers_Company::account" title="View Account Manager" module="Retailers_Company" sortOrder="20" parent="Retailers_Company::retailers" action="company/index/account" resource="Retailers_Company::account"/>
    <!--<add id="Retailers_Company::parent" title="Company" module="Retailers_Company" sortOrder="100" resource="Retailers_Company::parent"/>
    <add id="Retailers_Company::index" title="Company Index" module="Retailers_Company" sortOrder="10" action="company/index" resource="Retailers_Company::index" parent="Retailers_Company::parent"/>-->
    <!--<add id="Retailers_Company::add_row" title="Retailers Account Management" module="Retailers_Company" sortOrder="20" parent="Retailers_Company::retailers" action="company/company" resource="Retailers_Company::add_row"/>-->
</menu>
</config>
```

etc/adminhtml/acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
 <acl>
    <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="Retailers_Company::sample" title="Retailers" sortOrder="10" >
                <resource id="Retailers_Company::items" title="Retailers Account Management" sortOrder="20" />
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
  </acl>
</config>
```

Index.php(controller)

```
<?php
 namespace Retailers\Company\Controller\Adminhtml\Vendor;

 class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
 {
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
 */
protected $_resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context        $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}

/**
 * Grid List page.
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
 */
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Retailers_Company::items');
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Retailers Account Management'));

    return $resultPage;
}

/**
 * Check Grid List Permission.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Retailers_Company::items');
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Retailers_Company::items" title="Retailers Account Management" sortOrder="20" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you for replaying. I update this code on acl file but nothing to happend.

Comment: Did you rerun setup upgrade

Comment: Yes but nothing to happend

Comment: In this acl file how to get my custom menu? Because in this acl file did't define my custom menu Id

Comment: can you please post your full script so can see the issue